# OpenCV copy to Mat without transparent pixels

Tags: opencv

I have two images with the transparent background. I need to place both of these images with specific coordinates on the new OpenCV Mat **with white background**  (`out` Mat in the example below).

This is my current OpenCV code:

```
Mat out = new Mat(mat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

out.setTo(new Scalar(255));

Mat rotatedMat = Imgcodecs.imread(partOfRotatedImageFile.getAbsolutePath(), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
Rect roi = new Rect((int) (rect.center.x - rotatedMat.width() / 2), (int) (rect.center.y - rotatedMat.height() / 2), rotatedMat.width(), rotatedMat.height());
Mat outPart = null;
try {
     outPart = out.submat(roi);
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.err.println(e.getMessage());
     continue;
}
rotatedMat.copyTo(outPart);
```

In case the images overlap each other - one of them replaces the another image(that was previously placed) with transparent pixels.

For example:

[image]

Sorry for the bad image quality, but as you may see the left image with Alpha channel (presented with green rectangle) overlaps the right two images by Alpha channel.

Is it possible to update this code to copy everything from source Mat objects to the resulting Mat object except transparent pixels?

Comment: It could be that you aren't setting up all your Mat objects with alpha channels, for instance `Mat outPart = null;` and check you are reading them in as alpha `Mat rotatedMat`

Comment: Unfortunately no - `rotatedMat: Mat [ 76*200*CV_8UC4, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x257c09c0, dataAddr=0x2f9900a0 ]
outPart: Mat [ 76*200*CV_8UC4, isCont=false, isSubmat=true, nativeObj=0x257c0950, dataAddr=0x2940ec98 ]
out: Mat [ 3300*2552*CV_8UC4, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x257bf860, dataAddr=0x2759e060 ]`

Comment: create a new background Mat with white pixels. For each of your input pixels: copy/blend the pixel to your background mat according to the alpha channel value.